# Displaying more than one image in a GUI

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide

First and second images are displayed damaged
[image: Output for three images]

First original image
  [image]
Second original image
[image]

I have two `.bmp` images and I want to show them in two different axes in a Matlab GUI.

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

[imagedata1 imagemap1] = imread('C0.bmp');

axes (handles.axes1);

imshow(imagedata1, imagemap1);

[imagedata2 imagemap2] = imread('C1.bmp');

axes (handles.axes2);

imshow(imagedata2, imagemap2);
```

When I run this code, only the second image looks like its original appearance. The first one looks damaged.
When I try this for more than two images, again only the last one looks like its original appearance and the others look damaged.

What is the reason of that? How could I solve this problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. For me, your code works fine. Please note: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Schorsch I added an image

Comment: And this behaviour is related to the code-snippet in your question? Again, with the code you show I **cannot** reproduce a damaging effect on the images.

Comment: @Schorsch I added original images so you can understand mean of 'damaged'. And one more thing, my code-snippet for two image but I added screenshot include two image to make clear my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I convert my .bmp images to .png format and then use imshow to display them. Then my problem was solved.